How to make container scrollable but fill horizontally with React and Tailwind
I want a dashboard with a top and side bar and then the content in the middle. I want the content to be scrollable but I want it to fill the available height. The only issue is that when I try to fill the height it goes past the screen making the whole window scrollable and then is no longer scrollable itself. I have been reading its something to do with flex box but cannot tell. Im using React with typescript and Tailwindcss
App.tsx
import "./App.css";
import { Route, Routes, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Chat from "./components/Chat";
import ChatList from "./components/ChatList/ChatList";
import Topbar from "./components/Navigation/TopBar";
import Bottombar from "./components/Navigation/BottomBar";

function App() {

    return (
            <BrowserRouter>
            <div className="flex h-screen flex-col">
            <Topbar />
                <div className="grid grid-cols-8">
                    <div className="col-span-1"></div>
                    <div className="col-span-7">
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/chat/:id" element={<Chat />}></Route>
                        <Route path="/list" element={<ChatList />}></Route>
                    </Routes>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <Bottombar />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;


Chat.tsx
import MessagePane from "./MessagePane/MessagePane";
import "../App.css";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

interface ChatProps {
  id: number;
}

export default function Chat() {
  const { id } = useParams<{ id?: string }>();
    const chatId = id ? parseInt(id, 10) : undefined;

    if (chatId === undefined) {
        return <div>Invalid chat ID</div>; // Display an error message or handle the case where id is undefined
    }

    return (
    <div className="flex-grow overflow-hidden bg-red-400">
      <MessagePane id={chatId} />
    
    
    </div>
    );
}


MessagePane.tsx
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Message } from "../../interfaces/message.interface";
import ChatBubble from "./ChatBubble";
import "../../App.css";

interface MessagePaneProps {
    id: number;
}

export default function MessagePane({ id }: MessagePaneProps) {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Message[]>([]);
    const [renderedMessages, setRenderedMessages] = useState<Message[]>([]);
    const [loadCount, setLoadCount] = useState<number>(10); // Number of messages to load at a time
    const chatContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const topMessageIdRef = useRef<number | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchMessages = async () => {
            if (messages.length === 0) {
                try {
                    const response = await fetch(
                        `http://localhost:3000/messages/${id}`
                    );
                    if (response.ok) {
                        const data = await response.json();
                        setMessages(data); // Ensure messages are in the correct order
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error("Error fetching messages", error);
                }
            }
        };

        fetchMessages();
    }, [id]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (messages.length > 0) {
            setRenderedMessages(messages.slice(-loadCount));
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (chatContainerRef.current) {
                    chatContainerRef.current.scrollTop =
                        chatContainerRef.current.scrollHeight;
                }
            }, 0);
        }
    }, [messages]);

    const loadMoreMessages = () => {
        if (chatContainerRef.current) {
            const scrollTopBefore = chatContainerRef.current.scrollTop;
            const scrollHeightBefore = chatContainerRef.current.scrollHeight;

            const newRenderCount = Math.min(
                renderedMessages.length + loadCount,
                messages.length
            );
            setRenderedMessages(messages.slice(-newRenderCount));

            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                if (chatContainerRef.current) {
                    const scrollHeightAfter =
                        chatContainerRef.current.scrollHeight;
                    chatContainerRef.current.scrollTop =
                        scrollHeightAfter -
                        scrollHeightBefore +
                        scrollTopBefore;
                }
            });
        }
    };

    const handleScroll = () => {
        if (chatContainerRef.current) {
            const { scrollTop } = chatContainerRef.current;

            if (scrollTop === 0) {
                // Get the ROWID of the top message
                const topMessageElement = chatContainerRef.current.querySelector(
                    ".chat-container > div:first-child"
                );
                if (topMessageElement) {
                    const topMessageId = parseInt(
                        topMessageElement.getAttribute("data-rowid") || ""
                    );
                    topMessageIdRef.current = topMessageId;
                }

                loadMoreMessages();
            }
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const chatContainer = chatContainerRef.current;
        if (chatContainer) {
            chatContainer.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        }

        return () => {
            if (chatContainer) {
                chatContainer.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
            }
        };
    }, [renderedMessages]);

    // Scroll to the top message when new messages are loaded
    useEffect(() => {
        if (topMessageIdRef.current !== null) {
            const topMessageElement = document.querySelector(
                `#message-${topMessageIdRef.current}`
            ) as HTMLElement;
            if (topMessageElement && chatContainerRef.current) {
                chatContainerRef.current.scrollTop =
                    topMessageElement.offsetTop - chatContainerRef.current.offsetTop;
            }
        }
    }, [renderedMessages]);

    return (
        <div
            className="chat-container flex-grow overflow-y-auto"
            ref={chatContainerRef}
        >
            {renderedMessages.map((message: Message, index: number) => (
                <div
                    key={index}
                    id={`message-${message.ROWID}`}
                    data-rowid={message.ROWID} // Store the ROWID as data attribute
                >
                    <p>{message.ROWID}</p>
                    <ChatBubble sender={message.is_from_me} >
                        {message.text}
                    </ChatBubble>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}



Can you please create a StackBlitz snippet?

Or a tailwind play link would work, too: https://play.tailwindcss.com/ This doesn't sound a problem that has anything to do with react itself.

@RokBenko  its kind of tough to as the data comes from an api request so without the data the scrollable area wont populate

just give the scrollable area a min height or flex-1 with overflow as auto or scrollable..once doing this when populated with data it will be scrollable but when empty it should still fill the space of its parent due to the flex-1
